# Understanding and Implementing Access Control in Systems: User Profiles and Priorities

Tags: java, json, jwt

Please, could someone explain to me how an access control system works across multiple systems? My understanding is that access can be managed by profiles. For example, a 'seller' profile would have access to the sales control system, but within this system, there is a side menu where the 'seller' profile cannot enter or view certain routes, such as 'Pay Commission'. Let's imagine a side menu with 4 levels, where some routes are just for viewing and others for editing. How could I define this in an object, considering the user profile? Also, I have another question: if a user has two profiles, how do I determine which profile should have priority, since one profile can grant access while the other cannot?

Comment: This is way too board of a question to be answered in any meaningful way. Can you narrow it down to something more concrete? Maybe give some pseudo code to illustrate the problem? Also, you're using terms like _system_, _route_ etc that don't have a precise meaning, so I have to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: Normally, an access list is formed as: _user/group/role_ + _object id_ + _list of permissions_, answering who can perform what action of what object. E.g. for role-based access, ROLE_SELLER can perform VIEW, CREATE, EDIT, DELETE on SALES_CONTROL. So if ROLE_SELLER doesn't have VIEW on PAY_COMMISSION, they don't get to see that button or can't open `/pay_commission` URL or whatever. You can replace roles by user IDs or whatever is applicable in your system.